# Objects.isNull vs. Optional.ofNullable

Tags: java, java-8

I have this piece of code used in a test

```
if (Objects.isNull(o)) {
            return null;
        }
        return String.valueOf(o);
```

and when I replace this piece of code with

```
Optional.ofNullable(String.valueOf(o)).orElse(null);
```

I have this assertion error in my tests:

```
Expecting: <"null">
to be equal to: <null>
but was not.
```

Comment: And why dont you show us your testcase?

Comment: Probably String.valueOf(null) turns that into "null". What else would you expect?

Comment: By the way, `Objects.isNull(o)` is an awkward way to write `o==null`

Comment: You really shouldn't use `Optional` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional.ofNullable(String.valueOf(o))` will not be an empty optional when `o == null`, because `String.valueOf(null)` returns the String `"null"`.

The correct use of optional there is:

```
Optional.ofNullable(o).map(String::valueOf).orElse(null);
```

Where `ofNullable(null)` will make an empty optional, causing `orElse(null)` to be eventually invoked.

Comment: If you really want to use an API instead of the expression `o == null? null: o.toString()`, you should use [`Objects.toString(o, null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object,java.lang.String)). Guess, how it has been implemented…

Comment: That's really nice, @Holger

Answer (score 1):

String.valueOf() return toStirng() of an object if not null or return "null" string

straight from the String class:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

that means in your assertion you are testing "null" equals null which get fail.